# Using fill() on an Array while maintaining general structure in Julia

Tags: arrays, julia

For instance, if we have

```
a=[1 2;3 4]
```

We want to repeat each element (in a separate column) 2 times, resulting in:

```
[1 1 2 2;3 3 4 4]
```

I tried

```
hcat([fill(a[n],2) for n=1:length(a)]...)
```

but that returned

```
[1 3 2 4;1 3 2 4]
```

Any thoughts on how to achieve my desired results?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the [`repeat`](http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.5/stdlib/linalg/#Base.repeat) function:

```
julia> repeat(a, inner=(1, 2))
2×4 Array{Int64,2}:
 1  1  2  2
 3  3  4  4
```

The `inner` keyword specifies that you want to repeat the elements (and not the entire array itself), and the `(1,2)` specifies that the rows aren't repeated but the columns are duplicated.